# how to navigate from other component to child component in react native navigation version 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

**This is my home stack where I have been calling the screens component?**

**HomeStack**

```
<HomeStack.Navigator>
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Products" component={Products} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="BookmarkScreen" component={BookmarkScreen}/>
</HomeStack.Navigator>
```

**This is my HomeStack of TabNavigator and random I have to call a page in my home component**

**BookmarkScreen**

```
    <View>
       <BookmarkScreen navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
    </View>
```

**HomeScreen**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
         title="Go to details screen"
         onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Profile")}
      />
</View>
```

Getting an error of undefined props and the same error for navigation and if using in-class component and while exporting the component with props the error is same how to fix this issue in version 5 anyone knows let me know?

and in my class component, I used as const {navigation} = props; but still, the error is same can't navigate to the child component from another screen

Comment: You do not have a "Profile" component into the navigation stack. Do you mean "Products"?

Comment: yes Its product !!!

Comment: You really should accept my edit. This question is not understandable with this way.

Comment: ok sure do it i'll accept ? but i need solution